# Find a color that we see on an image from a distance

Tags: opencv, image-processing, physics, optics-algorithm

When we observe an image from a long distance it looks like a plain color.

Is there a known formula that could find which color will it be for a specific image?

Comment: You probably are talking about the mean color?

Comment: I thought about it at first, but I’m not sure if this is correct.